# replace the contents of an xml file with sed

Tags: shell, sed

i have one file which looks something like this

```
  <variable name="VOS_BRANCH">
    <name>VOS_BRANCH</name>
    <type>string</type>
    <value>cer_mainline</value>
  </variable>
  <variable name="VOS_BRANCH_LABEL">
    <name>VOS_BRANCH_LABEL</name>
    <type>string</type>
    <value>CER_FREEZE_12_0_0_98000_6_CCT</value>
  </variable>
```

so now here i want to replace the values CER_FREEZE_12_0_0_98000_6_CCT and cer_mainline to some other value that i am passing as a parameter to the script.

what i am doing now is

```
xml ed -u "/ENV_VARIABLES/variable[@name='VOS_BRANCH']/value" -v $new_branch_name $file > $file1
mv $file1 $file
xml ed -u "/ENV_VARIABLES/variable[@name='VOS_BRANCH_LABEL']/value" -v $new_branch_label $file > $file1
mv $file1 $file
```

but now the requirement is to use sed to do this operation.
and i am not sure how to use sed here

Comment: Why do you want to change the best way to a "not-so" efficient way with `sed`?

Comment: If more than one instances of `<value>cer_mainline</value>` and `<value>CER_FREEZE_12_0_0_98000_6_CCT</value>` are present, `sed` is not an efficient way. Any `xml` aware tool will be the ideal one.

Comment: Sed is going to be very brittle for the above need (matching bracketttes, matching tags). Xml aware tools are better. If you want to skip xml-aware tools, next better alternative is perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed "
    /<variable name=\"VOS_BRANCH\">/,/<\/variable>/ s@<value>.*</value>@<value>$new_branch_name</value>@;
    /<variable name=\"VOS_BRANCH_LABEL\">/,/<\/variable>/ s@<value>.*</value>@<value>$new_branch_label</value>@
" "$file"
```

That will write the new content to the terminal.  If you're satisfied,  you can either add `> "$file1"` as you had before, or you can add the `-i` option to `sed` to edit the file in-place.